# Using a NE555 for 12V boost to 24V to power an amplifier

Tags: power-supply, class-d, 555

I'm trying to draw a supply scheme for a class D integrated amplifier.

It requires 21V to 24V power supply and about 6/7A of current at 24V. The input is a car battery: 10V to 14.4V.

I found this on the web:

[image]

I've a few questions:

1. Is the NE555 usable for this scope?
2. How much output current this circuit have?
3. If the answers to the first two are: "no" and "too low" can you suggest a circuit scheme that it's my case?

EDIT: If you did not understand well, the scheme of this DC boost must be added to the PCB of the amplifier. Also, the output current can also be 3A, i will put two of this circuit in parallel with diodes.

EDIT_2: Ok then, I can't use a NE555, this is a scheme of a DC DC boost circuit that I already have and works very well for my application.

[image]

What resistance with what value I've to change to get a 21-24V output? Because it is adjustable, and it want fixed.

Comment: "*The output is a car battery ...*". I think you mean input. With Q1 and Q2 in that orientation you will never be able to pull C3 to V+ or to V-.

Comment: Yes, the input, sorry @Transistor

Comment: R1 is too low, and that's before we've got anywhere near to power. Visit Amadong or fleaBay, and buy a DC to DC boost converter module, 12v to 24v is a very common application.

Comment: I don't want to buy one, I'm trying to draw a scheme to add it to the same PCB of the amplifier @Neil_UK

Comment: @Northumber - "I don't want to buy one, I'm trying to draw a scheme to add it to the same PCB" Then you're out of luck, unless you want to do a great deal more work and make a much bigger pcb. Your current requirements simply cannot be met with a practical capacitively-driven circuit. C3 will need to be in the Farad range and the transistors are grossly inadequate, as is the drive for them. And the diodes, too. You need a standard DC-DC boost converter, and if you roll your own, at the very least you'll get horrendous noise injection unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Neil is right. You're wasting your time with a 555. Either create space on the PCB to mount a ready-made boost converter or design your own but you need to read the datasheets carefully and understand layout constraints. It will use less components and will actually regulate the voltage.

Comment: @Transistor see the EDIT_2 please

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast see the EDIT_2 please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It requires 21V to 24V power supply and about 6/7A of current at 24V.
>   The input is a car battery: 10V to 14.4V.

So the output power is about 22.5 volts x 6.5 amps = 146 watts.

Forget the circuit you have shown because it might deliver a couple of watts at best. Go for a proper boost regulator to step up 12 volts to 24 volts. Something like this: -

[image]

[image]

Comment: And only expect it to work if you use the exact inductor specified  - not just one with the same value that looks about the same size - unless you're willing to spend a lot of time learning the subtleties of inductor design. By the time you've built it and got it working, buying one will look like a much better option.

Comment: @BrianDrummond LOL

Comment: And expect at least one iteration of the pcb layout before you get _that_ right.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the LTC1270/1270A as a more highly integrated solution.  With a 10 A switch you should be able to get about 4 A output.  The data sheet is thin but the LT1070 datasheet and app note are great tutorials.

Answer (score -2):

> 've a few questions

Your switches will deliver 2x of the average current of 7a. With derating, you are likely talking about a pair of to247 devices for each side.

Check that against the datasheet specified there.

The topology here is a charge pump. They are simple but hard the champs at delivering loads of current.

Your power requirement is at the higher end of a single ended design. I would think about a fly back converter instead.